# How to deal with bad versioned software as SCM

Tags: version-control, configuration-management

I have been asked to be the SCM (Software Configuration Manager) in my company. I've read online documentation to learn what SCM is, what SCM does, etc.

Currently, the company works with a version control system (Bazaar), so the software is versioned correctly, but there are old programs that are not well versioned (some of them not versioned at all), some of them are in CVS, the old version control system used at first, but they are not updated.

I'm asking for your help, based on experience more than theoretical information, to know how to deal with this, how to be a good SCM even with all these issues.

Comment: I don't understand your question. It's up to the SCM, i.e. you to solve those issues and to find the best way to do it in a given context.

Comment: For existing software with no version control, the answer is easy - just stick the whole lot under version control.  It will end up as version 1.

Comment: In the future please do not cross post questions across StackExchange sites. If you feel you posted your question in the wrong place then please flag for a moderator and ask for it to be migrated for you.  Thank you.

Comment: @maple_shaft thanks for the advice, I didn't know that. It's the first time I have to migrate a post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a big task in front of you, and the details behind all of this could fill books.  Broadly speaking, here are the things you need to consider.

- Decide on a versioning scheme

Have a look at the [Wikipedia article on versioning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Versioning) to identify what versioning scheme you want to use.

- Version (or freeze) everything

Apply a version (and version control) on everything within your realm otherwise you won't be able to get a handle on what is in and what needs to be in the system.

- Build a dependency matrix

Next up is building a dependency matrix that shows what applications rely upon what versions of what components.  In a large application environment this *will* get messy due to the number of components to cover as well as the high number of individual or one-off components you'll find.

- Build a deployment matrix

Following that, you need to get a handle on what is actually out "in the wild" and deployed across your enterprise.  Challenges here will include tracking applications that haven't been versioned as well as the multitude of versions of an app that have been deployed.

- Establish a governance model

Once you have quantified the problem, you need to get technical and management buy-in so that everyone agrees there *is* a problem and that changes must be made in order to resolve the problem.  Decide how future versions will be identified and how dependent applications will be notified of updates.  Don't forget to include the Test / QA organization at this stage!

- Migrate all existing deployments to builds that have a version number

Remember all those unversioned and down-level applications that made your matrices a complete mess?  Time to start getting rid of them so you can simplify what you have to manage and the resulting governance overhead.

- Reduce the dependency and deployment matrices dimensions

Remember all those one-off dependency components?  Now it's time to merge and eliminate those for the same reasons that you migrated everyone to current levels.  Reducing the scope of what you have to manage is critical to establishing a successful program.

- (*Optional*) Reduce the number of source code repositories

There are bonus points at this stage if you can get the development teams to converge onto one code repository.  This will make the system administrators happy as there is less to maintain, and it should make the developers happy as they will be able to find the odd-ball dependent components more easily.